# How to reset a build parameter in TeamCity without having to click the reset button

Tags: teamcity

In a TeamCity build configuration, I have added a System parameter with name `"system.UploadCdn"`
and spec as below:

```
 "checkbox description='UploadCdn' label='UploadCdn' display='prompt' checkedValue='Upload'"
```

I need to reset this parameter to "Unchecked State" after the build completes without having to click on the Reset link.
As per [Is there a way to force a default value for a parameter in TeamCity and not lose it once a different value has been set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869349/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-default-value-for-a-parameter-in-teamcity-and-not-lose),
I have added a last build step as below.

```
Runner type: PowerShell Script : Source Code Script Source: ##teamcity[setParameter name='UploadCdn' value=' '] Script execution mode : Execute .ps1 from external file
```

But it is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tried these:
1. Reset parameter value of the project via API;
2. Reset parameter value of the build via API.

In both cases the value is set to what I send in with curl, but when the user click "Run...", the previously entered value shows up. If I click "Reset", the value is reset to the value I set via API.
So, you command, and my API are setting the default values in the configuration correctly, but the TeamCity UI caches the previously entered value.
I didn't find a way to clear that. But maybe this helps someone to figure it out.

Comment: Similar situation for me. I'm setting a pipeline with 40+ steps that are selected with a checkbox. I need these checkboxs to revert to their unchecked state after each build as sometimes we build again with a different set of configuration choices and our build is corrupted because there was a checkbox that didnt reset that we missed.